# Best or viable way to display image stored in varbinary field in MSSQL using VB.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have images stored in pdf, jpg , etc. in a varbinary field on an MSSQL server. I can extract them into a byte array, and convert them into a Base64 encoded string in a VB.NET API.

I need to display them on a web page for use in another application. Can I:

**a)** using `httpresponse` display them directly from the API? By setting the media type to the appropriate image type?

**b)** Currently most of the controllers in the solution inherit from the `APIController` which doesn't appear to allow access to `ViewBag`, etc. But if I change the controller to inherit from `Controller`, I am unable to access the method. I get a `404 error` or `URI doesn't exist` error. This solution is easy in C# by setting the data in `ViewBag` to the Base64 encoded string that displays in a view.

**c)** access the API from an .aspx page from another web vb.net solution using jquery to parse the parameters passed in the query string.

I am not sure what approach is do-able. It seems like this should be a relatively easy thing to do.

C# Example

```
Dim documentImageByteArray = documentTable.Rows(0).Item("DocumentData")
Dim Image = ("data:image;base64," + 
    Convert.ToBase64String(documentImageByteArray))
```

ViewBag.ImageData = Image
Return View()`

Comment: Are you using asp.net-mvc?

Comment: Yes, I am using asp.net-mvc - vb.net

Comment: if it's a web API controller then option a would be sensible. Just set the `src` of the `img` tag to the URL of the API which fetches the image data (make sure it accepts GET requests). You don't need to convert to base64, just return the binary data with correct headers.

Comment: You can do anything you put your mind to, I expect. Which one is best is something you'll need to determine through your own testing.

Comment: ADyson - your answer was perfect - can you please post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's a web API controller then option a would be sensible. Just set the src of the img tag to the URL of the API which fetches the image data (make sure it accepts GET requests). You don't need to convert to base64, just return the binary data with correct headers. –
ADyson
Feb 15, 2019 at 20:46

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).